# How can I automate integration testing for secondary displays on Android?

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, android-espresso

Our app is deployed on POS systems that have a customer-facing-display. I’m having trouble coming up with a good solution for automating testing around the content on the secondary screen. We primarily use Presentations to serve the content, which is an implementation of a Dialog.

Any thoughts?

I tried using Espresso but found that I was only matching views on the main activity view. Perhaps I’m missing something with espresso?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.